# Free web-based DNS tool for viewing DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system

Is there a good and **free** web-based service, that lets me see all `DNS` records (`A`, `MX`, `SOA`, etc.) for a given domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DNSQueries.com](http://www.dnsqueries.com/en/) is another option. I used to use DNSStuff more until they turned into a paid service. You could also checkout [IPTools.com](http://www.iptools.com/) if you like that style of layout better.

Comment: +1 for DNSQueries. I dind't know it before, it's an amazing collection of tools. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

DNSStuff.com has some good tools.

mxtoolbox.com also is good for MX record lookup, but they tend to cache records after the initial request.

Try dnscolos.com as well. That one generates a large amount of useful information and tips.

Comment: Dnsstuff looks like it might do the job, but it is not free (I added the free requirement after you asked).

Comment: dnscolos gives you just about everything. Run one and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: dnscolos does not give me all the a-records - just the a-record of the domain itself (and maybe for www, I dont remember). Am I missing something?

Comment: I know you asked for web-based, but what's discouraging you from using nslookup command line on a PC, or GUI Network Utility on a Mac?

Comment: ...That I can never remember the correct syntax, since I don't do this very often.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search will turn up lots. I just tried http://www.digdns.org/dig-dns and http://www.kloth.net/services/dig.php and both seemed to work well and allow the selection of different record types.

Additionally, ISPs often provide these tools on their websites for customers who don't have native tools on their own computers.

Finally, dig and nslookup locally, whilst not web-based out of the box, are readily available on most platforms and it is possible to write a script to make them web-based locally.

Answer (score -1):

And, what is wrong with `nslookup`?

Comment: At what point did nslookup get a web interface?